# Precargar SOAP en PHP

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Estoy usando un webservice en el cual realizo la conexión por SOAP en PHP.

El problema viene cuando en la primera llamada, a veces, no se recuperan los datos y hay que darle otra vez al botón de consulta para verlos.

¿Existe alguna manera de que esta conexión se precargue, o algo similar, para que funcione desde la primera conexión?

El código que uso es este:

```
$servicio="http://1.1.1.1/WS/Ws.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($servicio, $parametros);
$result = $client->getContratos($parametros);
```

En el hago la llamada cuando hay un check seleccionado en la web.

En $parametros van diferentes parametros, según lo que se haya rellenado por el usuario.

Como digo arriba, la primera vez que actúa devuelve en blanco siempre, pero de la segunda en adelante funciona perfecto.

Si lo pruebas directamente en la consola del webservice va bien, siempre.

Comment: Ya está Mariano, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

hola al momento de inicializar los parametros del cliente deberia ser la configuracion de tu soap cliente como por ejemplo:

```
$client     = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
```

en el caso de consumir el servicio deben de ser los parámetros que le envías a la función del webservice que consumiras.

```
$result = $client->getContratos($parametros);
```

en el caso de que requieras visualizar que le estás enviando puedes revisar el siguiente link:
http://php.net/manual/es/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

en el caso de que requieras visualizar lo que te esta devolviendo te recomiendo este link.

http://php.net/manual/es/soapclient.getlastresponse.php

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos.